# Когда нужно использовать Pair?

Tags: java

Всем привет! Пишу `Converter.Factory` для `Retrofit`. Мне приходит HTML код, поэтому я написал так

```
public class DocumentConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {

    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        return DocumentConverter.INSTANCE;
    }

    final static class DocumentConverter implements Converter<ResponseBody, Document> {
        static final DocumentConverter INSTANCE = new DocumentConverter();

        @Override
        public Document convert(ResponseBody responseBody) throws IOException {
            return Jsoup.parse(responseBody.string());
        }
    }
}
```

Но, помимо `Document` мне еще нужен код сессии, который надо вынуть из `Document`. Оно представляет собой значение `Long`. Что мне использовать для хранения этих обоих данных? Создать модель `Page`, внутри которого будет `Document document` и `long sessionKey`. Или же использовать `Pair<Document, Long>`? Если здесь `Pair` не уместен, то где он уместен?

Comment: Если этот Long есть в Document, то зачем дублировать данные и городить огород?

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, этот `Long` трудно достается из `Document` посредством парсинга. Зачем мне везде его вынимать, если можно это сделать в одном месте, чтобы он везде приходил отдельно?

Comment: Ок, тогда если Long будет нужен большинству получателей Document, то логично вернуть Pair<Document, Long>. Не стоит только ради этого плодить еще одну сущность.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, ага, понял. А есть ли разница между `Pair<Document, Long>` и `Pair<Long, Document>`? И, кстати, если юзать `Pair`, то другой разработчик не поймет, что это за `Long` такой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекомендую создать модель Page, в которой будут все необходимые данные и которая не будет ничего знать о деталях доступа к данным (Document - это ведь класс из JSoup?) и создавать объект типа Page фабрикой ретрофита. В таком случае если вы захотите изменить фабрику, парсить сайт другой библиотекой, модель не будет затронута. Pair в данном случае лучше не использовать, так как лучше задавать объекты модели явно и есть опасность при злоупотреблении столкнуться с вложенными парами к примеру.

Использовать Pair я считаю уместно в максимально ограниченных контекстах, например в Rx:

```
Observable<Pair<Integer>> obs = Observable.zip(users, photos, 
(user, photo) -> new Pair<User, Photo>(user, photo));

obs
  .filter(pair -> pair.first.age > 30)
  .subscribe(pair -> show(pair.second));
```

здесь я думаю было бы лишним создавать сущность для юзера с фото, и так с первого взгляда ясно что проиходит.

Comment: Верно подмечено, спасибо за разъяснения